# Javascript code editor for edit html of page by user to create template and custom the page

Tags: editor

I need an editor for html tags, i want to make it for next developer to edit pages online, so, an editor with highlighter tags feature and IntelliSense needed.
Something like this: 
http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/exemples/exemple_full.html

but with format and IntelliSense features.

Comment: I found this http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding

Answer (score 0):

I found this editor, great and powerful.

http://ace.c9.io/ [image]